# Lock positions of child object in parent-child relationship with math

Tags: math, position, transform, parent

This is a small problem I'm trying to solve with math. I'm trying to lock any position and rotation of child object. I tried to use the range mapper (`if parent.pos.x = 30, then cild.pos.x = - 30`), but it takes a long time to enter values manually and now work well.

Is there any formula for blocking the transformation of an child object? (I can transform just local position of a child, not a global)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raOTI.png)

Comment: This question is highly unclear. What are you trying to do, and how does your effort fail?

Comment: I am just trying to keep the position of the child when the parent moves. Also I can only control the local coordinate of the child. So, it looks like I am trying to compensate for the parental move by moving the child.

Comment: Try reading your question as if you *didn't* know what it was about. What is a "child object"? Why should one object move when another moves? What is the "local position" or "local coordinate" of an object? Does that refer to a particular coordinate frame, perhaps one fixed to the body of the "parent object"? Do you want to (I'm going out on a limb here) apply a translation/rotation to an object using global coordinates, and then calculate the inverse operation *in the coordinate frame of the object?*

Comment: The child object is being moved because it is in a relationship with the parent object (please see the screenshot in the post above). When parent move his global coordinate changes(as a child too), but local coordinate of the child do not changes(child.local.position = 0,0,0; child.global.position = 5,22,0.5 - just for example.). It's becous relationship. So, in my case i can't change a global coordination of a child , just local(becouse exercise). Question: "How i can keep position of a child by change just local coorditane?" If you have other questions, just message me. Thanks